# custom vscode extension not working over ssh

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I created a vscode extension for the first time..I used LSP(language server protocol) and having both client and server bundled as one extension.

The extension has highlighting and autocomplete features for a custom file type. I packaged it using `vsce` I got a VSIX file. I installed the extension in my vscode using the .vsix file.

The extension works when i am working on local files.

However, i connected to a remote VM using the `ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh` extension such that I can view the remote files in vscode, but here my created extension is not working. I can't even see the file type i created.

Any help is appreciated. Is there some specific setting I need to put in my `package.json`

Answer (score 1):

For your extension to properly work remotely, either installed on host or on the remote, you have to follow a few guidelines, and yes, there are some settings that you may take care of on `package.json`.

The first and more complete source of information is [Supporting Remote Development and GitHub Codespaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/remote-extensions) API documentation. It describes the architecture, settings, how to debug, common problems and so on. There is also the Extension Host page, where it describes the [Preferred extension location](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/extension-host#preferred-extension-location) topic, which tells you how to configure your extension to work on the *correct* location.

Based on your description (a LSP related extension) I understand your extension should be a [Workspace Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/remote-extensions#architecture-and-extension-kinds). This means that you should have this on your `package.json`:

```json
    "extensionKind": [
        "workspace"
    ]
```

The Commons Problem section describes how you can evaluate and fix [Incorrect execution location](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/remote-extensions#incorrect-execution-location). To debug using SSH follow [these instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/remote-extensions#debugging-using-ssh).

Also, remember that while working with remotes, you rely on *local paths* anymore. Instead you must always deal with `Uri`, whenever possible.

I guess after reviewing your settings, based on the docs related above, you should be able to detect what is happening on your extension and fix it. Give debug a try, it will be much easier to detect issues than installing the `vsix` and look for erros in `Console`.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the pointers. I set the extensionKind to workspace but then it seems user has to install the extension for every remote connection. I then set it to ui, and installed extension in local. This way syntax highlighting works even when connected to remote, but autocomplete is not working! Apparently it should work...any idea why its not coming up on remote.

Comment: Based on your extension’s description, it _seems_ to be “workspace” (because it deals with workspace files), and in this case yes, the extension needs to be installed on the remote. But, if you developed your LSP with no _hard requirement_ on workspace file, and it can work with remote/virtual file system, you could try to use “ui” instead. I have a few extension that _should_ be “workspace” but are “ui” instead, because I don’t depend on absolute files. You will have to play with the setting to find the one that fits with your extension.

Comment: You may have noticed that `extensionKind` supports multiple values, where you can define an _order_ of preference. Most of my extensions are defined as [“ui”, “workspace”], because it _preferes_ to be local, but _can_ be installed on remotes as well. Maybe, because your extension has an LSP, could be the opposite [“workspace”, “ui”]. But still, having “workspace” on it, it should require to be installed on remotes, when connected to remotes

Comment: yes, i dont want it to be installed on remote. "ui" is the right setting for me. And it is working too. its just that its working partially..(syntax highlighting working, autocomplete not working) need to find the "setting" to make it work.

Comment: If you don’t wan’t it to be installed on remotes, you have to be sure the LSP/autocomplete piece of your extension properly supports _remote/virtual_ workspaces. There are some limitations and approaches you have to be aware, otherwise it won’t work. The same references provided above presents documentation about it.